# Erc1155 - how does multisig mint

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, erc-1155

In OZ's erc1155, it seems there's only `_mint` function that calls `_doSafeTransferAcceptanceCheck` in the end which all the time checks that if receiver is contract, it should have the function `onERC1155Received` implemented on it.

1. Why is this restricted in ERC1155 and not in ERC721 ? in erc721, you can decide to use _mint or safeMint, but there's no option to decide in erc1155.
2. if so, how can multisig call mint on erc1155 and succeed ? multisig(gnosis let's say doesn't have `onERC1155Received` on it ..

Thank you.